# Storing scraped data from a website using importXML and scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to scrape data from a website once a day using Google sheets and then storing it to the side with a script. I'm new to this so I can't seem to get it to work... This is what I'm using to scrape data from a website:

```
=importxml("https://www.reddit.com/top/", "//div [@data-rank='1']")
```

Then I want to store the result somewhere... I think with appendrow? But it keeps giving me errors and I don't know how to fix it. My script looks like this so far (but it errors out):

```
function addData() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.appendRow(['=importXML("https://www.reddit.com/top/", "//div [@data-rank='1']")']);
}
```

Also would like to add the date of when the data is extracted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You can set a daily timed trigger to run it. In the script editor go to the edit menu. Click current project triggers Add a new trigger for Archive. A timed trigger, daily, pick a time to run and save.

```
function Archive() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")//sheet with imported data
  var s2=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2")//archive sheet
  var lr=s2.getLastRow()+1//get last row of archive sheet + 1
  var data=s1.getRange(2,1,1,4).getValues()//get sheet 1 values
  s2.getRange(lr,1,1,1).setValue(new Date())//create date and set in 
  s2.getRange(lr, 2, 1, 4).setValues(data)//set copy of data
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! I just adjusted the getRange to match sheet1's data